# Finding uppercase acronyms in a string

Tags: python, string, loops, uppercase

I'm trying to find uppercase acronyms in a string. For example, if the input is "I need to see you ASAP, because YOLO, you know" should return ["ASAP", "YOLO"].

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import string


def acronyms(s):

    s.translate(string.punctuation)
    for i, x in enumerate(s):
        while x.upper():
            print(x)
            i += 1


def main():
    print(acronyms("""I need to see you ASAP, because YOLO, you know."""))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to get rid of the punctuations, then loop through the string, and while it is uppercase print the letter out. It resulted in an infinite loop. I wanted to solve this using string manipulation, so no RegEx

***Edits***:

1. changes in removing punctuations for efficiency

From:

```
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
        s = "".join(ch for ch in s if ch not in exclude)
```

To:

```
s.translate(string.punctuation)
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple things I'd like to point out. One, you have end up with a hanging program because you have a `while True` and not a single `break`. Then, you kind of make the `enumerate` pretty pointless when you do `n+=1`.

```
for i, x in enumerate(s):
    n+=1
```

This can all be easily simplified, no `enumerate needed`.

```
def acronyms(s):

    exclude = set(string.punctuation)
    s = "".join(ch for ch in s if ch not in exclude)
    acro = [x for x in s.split() if x.isupper()]
    return acro
```

output

```
['I', 'ASAP', 'YOLO']
```

Sadly, we do have an extra `I` which happens not to be an acronym, so one fix could be to make sure `x` is never one letter before being appended.

```
acro = [x for x in s.split() if x.isupper() and len(x) != 1]
```

Comment: nice one for building on the OP code, but I really think that using `s.split()` and the `exclude` object is not the way to go. It gets the job done but it is so far from producing a robust tokenisation

Comment: @Matt Not to be that guy, but stack overflow is not a place to write entire code for poeple. By giving people the entire answer they will not learn from it.

Comment: I tried implementing this and some of the answers resulted in a tuple instead of a string so I'll try to find a way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your while-loop iterates over the first character, but never breaks out to go to the next character.

You also want to filter out the 'I' as a single letter is not usually classified as an acronym.

the `string.isupper()` function checks for an entire string rather than a single character, so I recommend you use that. It would look like this:

```py
def acronyms(s):
    words = s.split()
    acronyms = []
    for word in words:
        if word.isupper() and len(word) > 1:
            acronyms.append(word)
    return acronyms
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using `nltk` for its wonderful tokenisation package, it handles edge cases and punctuation superbly.

For a simplified approach where you define an acronym as:

- all characters are alphabetical
- all characters are upper case

The following should suffice:

```py
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def get_acronyms(text):
    return [
        token for token in word_tokenize(text)
        if token.isupper()
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

here this should work:

```
def acronyms(x):
  ans = []
  y = x.split(" ")
  for i in y:
    if i.isupper():
      ans += [i]
  return ans
```

isupper() returns `True` as long as there are no lowercase even if there is punctuation